# How Hive Bucketing are benificial for map side join?

Tags: hive

I understand what is bucket in hive, and i do have deep knowledge of it.
I am going through [hive documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL+BucketedTables) and there it is mentioned that:

> Bucketed tables are fantastic in that they allow much more efficient
>   sampling than do non-bucketed tables, and they may later allow for
>   time saving operations such as mapside joins.

Can anybody explain that how bucketing is beneficial for map side join?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shuffle stage is really expensive since it needs to sort and merge.Saving shuffle and reduce stages improves the task performance.The motivation of map join is to remove shuffle and reduce phases and do the join in Map phase itself .By doing so,when one of the table is small enough to fit in the memory,all the mappers can hold the data in memory and do the join work there.
So in Sort Merge bucketed join ,both the tables are bucketed and number of buckets in one table is half of the other table.As of one of the bucketed table is small enough to be fit in memory ,so we can take the advantage of Map join here by skipping the shuffle and reduce phase entirely.

[Example of bucketed join](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htmV0.png)

Comment: Thanks Abid. Makes sense

Comment: Also,would like to add what ,Bucketing can be only done when table is sorted and bucketed by key.What sorting does is that all the key reside in same area of disk ,which makes join easy as same key are grouped together which is not possible in normal join because they are spread across the cluster and is expensive in terms of network utilization standpoint.